# How to reset Jenkins to its factory settings?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have installed Jenkins on my Red Hat server [following this tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions). But by mistake I skipped the default plugins part.

I tried deleting `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` but this file getting created again and again.

- How can I get back to the initial setting where I can do it correctly this time?
- Or is there a way I can go to default plugin installation without doing much changes?

I tried googling but all the documents that match are for resetting admin passwords.

> NOTE: I do know that I can go to plugin management and install the
>   plugins I want. However, I'm currently ended up with a blank slate and
>   I'm not sure which are all the plugins I should install.

Answer (score 1):

An earlier answer mentioned a .jenkins file or folder. At least on my jenkins instance on CentOS no such file exists.

edit `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` and change the following line to:

`<installStateName>NEW</installStateName>`

then 
service jenkins restart

[image]

Comment: I will try this out

Comment: I just get a blank screen now when I go to the base URL. F12 shows it loading the base page and a whole bunch of css and js files. Then nothing. Blank white screen. View page source shows HTML and the title is <title>SetupWizard [Jenkins]</title>

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the provided tutorial link, I assume you installed jenkins with your package manager.

Use your package manager to look what files were installed with the Jenkins package using this command: `rpm -ql jenkins` (for debian based distros `dpkg -L jenkins`). You will notice it installs configuration files in `/etc`, service files in `/lib` and doc/binaries in `/usr`. Also, it creates these 3 folders for its working directory, logs and cache:

```
/var/cache/jenkins
/var/lib/jenkins
/var/log/jenkins
```

Basically, you need to reset the files/folders to their original state by deleting everything that Jenkins wrote in the `/var` folders. This is assuming that you did not modify `/etc` or `.service` files

### TL;DR

- Stop the service with `systemctl stop jenkins.service` (sudo if needed)
- Wipe out the working directory, logs and cache with `rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/* /var/cache/jenkins/* /var/log/jenkins/*`
- Start jenkins back with `systemctl start jenkins.service` (sudo if needed)

Comment: Worked for me with Ubuntu 22.04 - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .jenkins file. I just had the same problem (similar) and I deleted the .jenkins folder. It should bring you back to the setup.

Comment: Where's that file typically located?

Answer (score 0):

**I know resetting and reinstalling is not the same thing, but it might be the right thing to do in this situation.**

I suggest you uninstall jenkins completely and then reinstall it. I tried it as well with the answers mentioned above, but nothing did what I wanted (I forgot to install the Plugins, just like you). I did it on a Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Uninstall:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum -y remove jenkins
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/jenkins
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/
```

Install:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat- stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum -y install jenkins

sudo service jenkins start
```

Source for Red Hat install / uninstall: https://gist.github.com/springaki/1add83b255c2d38800e5c3d864cbb737

Answer (score -1):

Check this link https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-2.19.4/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/install/platform-plugins.json list of succested plugins. You can install this plugins manually.

Comment: You may have misread the question. It's not about the plugins. It's about resetting settings.